# VerifyError with ShinobiControls and Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, shinobi, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm running into this strange VerifyError when trying to run Robolectric tests that call ShinobiControls under the hood. I've tried the -noverify option, but it doesn't seem to be working, or I'm putting it in the wrong place.

I'm using Retrolambda, Java 8, Robolectric (3.0), and Shinobi Premium (1.8.0).

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 18
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/shinobicontrols/charts/ChartFragment.onResume()V @8: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab7 000b 2ab4 0006 c600 0a2a b400 06b6
    0x0000010: 0012 b1                                

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:611)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
    at com.example.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:132)
```

Comment: What versions are you using of all these components (i.e. shinobicharts, Roboelectric and Retrolambda)?

Comment: We also use shinobi and we mock shinobi view in Robolectric tests

Comment: @safarmstrong Robolectric 3.0, Shinobi Premium 1.8.0

Comment: @EugenMartynov Do you see this issue? Or does it work for you?

Comment: We mock it. I will write answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we are facking shinobi view. We have next construction:

```
public class ShinobyView {
    @VisibleForTesting
    @NonNull
    protected ChartView getShinobiChart(@NonNull final LayoutInflator inflator, @NonNull final ViewGroup chartContainer) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.shinobi_chart, chartContainer, false);
    }

    @NonNull
    public View createView(@NonNull context context) {
       ...
       ChratView view = getShinobiChart(inflator, container);
       container.addView(view, <some layout params>);
       ...
    }
}
```

And in test we fake it:

```
public class TestShinobyView {
    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected ChartView 
    getShinobiChart(@NonNull final LayoutInflator inflator, @NonNull final ViewGroup chartContainer) {
        return new View(activity);
    }
}
```

If you want to verify that you also correctly setup shinobi charts then you need to mock `ShinobiChart` and return not `View` but faked `ShinobiView`

Comment: Thanks Eugen! So, it doesn't successfully compile for you? Are those classes in your Test directory?

Comment: It does compile for us. The top code is production and the bottom one is from tests

Comment: Could you also please show how you expose that in XML? I'd like to see how our implementations are the same/differ, so I can mess around.